# can windows media player show milliseconds

Tags: media-player, windows-media-player

As i was looking to split a tutorial video file(`.wmv`) with this amazing tool called [Asfbin](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-software-cut-split-or-merge-video-files.htm#AsfBinWin), looked every settings in media player but in vain couldn't find one...

Is there a way to set windows media player to display the time with `milliseconds` along with `hour:minute:seconds`?

my current media player ver: 12.0.7601.17514 running on `Win 7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was searching for a similar thing in the past, couldn't find any solution , but I moved on to `media player classic` and I would pause at a particular place in the video to check the current time in `milliseconds` by hitting `Ctrl+G` ....

Though this seems a bit messy but slowly started living with this :)   , and I will do so until someone finds a better option, or if u find anything better post ur answer here..

Answer (score 8):

Use **media Player Classics**!
You can make a **right click on the Position label** and then ***click on "high precision"***

So you can see the position in millisecond *without clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> every time*.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution - I was looking for a millisecond display and ability to precisely move the playback point, but for mp4 files:

AviDemux
http://www.videohelp.com/tools/AviDemux

Works very nicely for me! (041214 64-bit beta on Windows 7).

Comment: `Media Player Classic` has been discontinued since 2017 and doesn't seem to support many modern video files. AviDemux is still in development and actually works with the files I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering for Media Player Classic.

To show milliseconds go to `View`->`Subresync` (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>).

For this to work, you need to add a subtitle. If you don't have one, just create a text file, rename the extension to `.srt` and add something like this:

> 1
>   00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:20.000
>   Hello

I tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> solution but it wasn't very accurate. In fact, when I clicked `Go!` it actually moved me to a different frame instead of staying there.

Hope this helps.